# After upgrade, computer won't boot

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

I went through the upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS the other day. The process went without a hitch until restart, when all I have is a black screen. This black screen occurs after the Login page, and after I enter my password.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please edit the question and include your hardware specs (graphics card, etc.). Did you install any graphics drivers? What about previous proprietary drivers like Nvidia if you use Nvidia, AMDGPU if you have AMD GPU, etc. Also, are you able to access recovery mode for Ubuntu from the Grub menu?

Comment: Also if you reply back, use @mchid at the beginning of the comment (or other username) so the user (me) will get a notification of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall desktop.

1. Go in single user mode by pressing CTRL+ALT+F4.
2. Run
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
3. If it fixes issue, then fine, otherwise try

   sudo service lightdm restart

see if it fixes issue and share observations.